# Using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi and AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp in the same ASP.NET Core 7 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to serve both Web API and Razor on an ASP.NET Core 7 application protected by MSAL with Azure AD. If I call just `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`, I can call my Web API with `PublicClientApplication` passing an `AccessToken`, but then the Razor pages are served with a http 401 error.

If I call `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` after `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`, my Razor pages authenticate properly and serve but my Web API returns with an HTML document.

The code I am using in my `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi();
```

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net" crossorigin>
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">

    <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedSignIn" />
    <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
    <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />

        <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled" />
    </noscript>
    
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
<!-- a bunch of script stuff -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

And adding to my API Controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Special thanks to Suchiman on Libera!